# Why data is not getting pushed in the array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

This is the `Cart.jsx`,

```
import { createContext, useEffect } from "react"
import "./Cart.css"
import Cake from "../About Section/Cake";
const PdtList = createContext();
let list = [];
export default function Cart() {
    return (
        <>
            <main className="align" >
                <h1>Thanks for shopping with us</h1>
                <PdtList.Provider value={list}>
                    <Cake />
                </PdtList.Provider>

            </main>
        </>
    )
}
export { PdtList };
```

And this is the `Cake.jsx`

```
import "./Product.css"
import { PdtList } from "../Cart/Cart";
import { useContext  , useState , useEffect} from "react";
export default function Cake(props) {
  const { name, images, bold, cut } = props;
  const newList = useContext(PdtList);
  console.log("this is something " , newList);
  const [value, setvalue] = useState(newList);
  const Add_Products = (index) => {
    // console.log('Add_Products called');
    let tobeAdded = { name, images, bold };
    setvalue((e) => [...e, tobeAdded]);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, [value])
    return (
        <>
            <main className="align unique">
                <img src={images} alt="" />
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <div className="align2">
                    <small>Rs {bold}</small>
                    <small style={{ "margin": "0px 10px" }} ></small>
                    <small style={{ "font-size": "15px", "textDecoration": "line-through" }} >Rs {cut}</small>
                </div>
                <button onClick={Add_Products} style={{ "margin": "10px 0px" }}>Add to Cart</button>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

I was trying to use `useContext` but I am not able to push data in the array in `Cake.jsx` using useState.

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: e is not iterable`.

[image]

Comment: Did you check that `newList` is not undefined?

Comment: Initially the newList is `[]` but after that `undefined` I have added the image.

Comment: I have added a codesand box link. `https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-curran-opek1i?file=/src/Cart.jsx`

Comment: in your image you are showing another error, I just updated my answer take a look

Comment: e context is set to the value its being called  form your spreading the button html elements e value which is undefined

Comment: @Ankit https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-lumiere-czs63p?file=/src/Cake.jsx

Comment: Please check this link I have added a file and it still says `https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-currying-rzo6zd?file=/src/Birthday.jsx`